# Why systemd-analyze from systemd service at multi-user.target does not output anything

Tags: shell-script, systemd

Having the following script:
 **boot-time-log.sh**

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

BOOT_TIME=$(systemd-analyze | cut --fields=10 --delimiter=\ )
echo -e "Boot time: $BOOT_TIME\n" > /var/log/boot_time.txt
```

And the following systemd service (enabled):
 **log_at_boot.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Log boot time 
User=root
Group=root

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/boot-time-log.sh

[Install]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
Wants=multi-user.target
After=multi-user.target
```

When I restart the PC the contents of /var/log/boot_time.txt are:

```
Boot time:
```

And if I run the script manually, then the contents are:

```
Boot time: 29.382s
```

How can I get the service execution to have the same output than the manual execution?

Comment: I used a systemd timer for 15 seconds from "OnStartupSec", and works (There is proper output). If I use less seconds of delay, the output of systemd-analyze is empty. Does somebody know why the output of systemd-analyze is empty if executed too early? And if there is a cleaner way to get this result?

Comment: I started down the path of `while ! systemctl is-active "$(systemctl get-default)"` but didn't get to the bottom of it, in case anyone wants to extend it from there.

Comment: A little further along, the `analyze` process appears to [ask the DBus](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/1ace223ca74032a224950665438311eb688f1e05/src/analyze/analyze.c#L233) to populate the (various) boot times, which a reference to "active jobs" which is probably why an (active) service can never succeed in asking for the boot time yet a delayed (timer'd) service can.